# Create Index Routes in react-router v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have multiple routes in my project and for now I want to redirect '/' url to '/path1' everytime the page loads. I tried making '/path1' as the index route but it is keeping me '/' url only i.e the Home component. How do I make it go to path1?

```
    <Routes>
 <Route path="/" element={<Home/>} >
            <Route index path="path1" element={<OneComponent/>} />
            <Route path="path2" element={</TwoComponent>} />
            <Route path="path3" element={<ThreeComponent/>} />
            </Route>
          </Routes>
```

Answer (score -1):

It look like you are trying to [use a Layout](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#layout-routes). Here is an example on how you can implement it :

App.jsx :

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './home.jsx';
import Layout from './layout.jsx';
import Page1 from './page1.jsx';
import Page2 from './page2.jsx';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
          <Route index element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="page1" element={<Page1 />} />
          <Route path="page2" element={<Page2 />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

layout.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Outlet, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Layout = () => (
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <Link to="/">Home</Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to="page1">Page 1</Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to="page2">Page 2</Link>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <br />
    <Outlet />
  </div>
);

export default Layout;
```

Note the use of `<Outlet />` in the layout that allow you to display the index route. The index route will be rendered when the path defined in the parent is hit. Here it's `"/"` from `<Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>`.

Also note that this does not make changes in your url. By that I mean there is no defined url for `Layout` since it is not really a common route. If you want your parent route (here layout) to have its own url, then you could use nested routes and use `<Navigate to="whatever" />`.

Here is [a repro on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-agcxus?file=src%2Fhome.jsx,src%2Fpage1.jsx,src%2Fpage2.jsx,src%2FApp.js,src%2Flayout.jsx) if you want to play with routes.